# Should I see evidence of neutron induced gammas on a background spectrum?

Tags: nuclear-physics, spectroscopy, data-analysis, gamma-rays

If I am looking at a background gamma spectrum taken from a neutron spallation source whilst the beam was off (IE in a shutdown period), should I expect to see emissions coming from neutron induced reactions?

I have a peak at 834keV which I can't really attribute to anything other than a 72Ge(n,n') reaction. I am using a Germanium detector, but should I really be seeing evidence of (n,n') reactions on a background spectrum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would note that Mn54 has a 300 day half life, and also emits at 834keV - you are likely seeing activation of material from the past neutron activity (Mn is a fairly standard alloying addition in steels and aluminum alloys).